# How to use a handle as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, winapi

I was writing code for a win32 application when I came across a problem, how to use a handle as a function parameter. For instance whit this function:

```
void refreshWindow (HWND myWNDhandle)
{
    InvalidateRect(myWNDhandle, NULL, FALSE);
}
```

If I would pass in "hwnd" as the parameter and run the code, like this:

```
refreshWindow (hwnd);
```

I would assume my window will be painted again, unfortunately my window won't.
What did i do wrong?

Comment: add this line to refreshWindow method: assert (IsWindow(myWNDhandle));

Comment: This is the correct way to use a handle as a function parameter. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You must call UpdateWindow() after InvalidateRect().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechanically your call is perfect. So either the HWND itself is invalid and, as other commenters suggest, you should assert on IsWindow() to validate that, or you are falling victim to the asynchronous nature of window repainting:

Calling `InvalidateRect` will merely mark the window as in need of painting, and a subsequent call to `GetMessage` will generate a paint message to paint the window if there are no other higher priority events or messages to process.

Typically then, methods that want to refresh the contents of a window immediately, follow the call to `InvalidateRect` with a call to `UpdateWindow` - which will ensure the window is repainted before returning.